# Keep a div visible after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selection

I have a div, `<div class="sectionCarouselCapabillities"> ... </div>` which - by default - is hidden from sight unless you make a change to a drop down. So the following:

```
    $('.carouselUser').change(function(){
        $('.sectionCarouselCapabillities').show()
    });
```

States that when select box - with class: `carouselUser` changes state, we show the div `sectionCarouselCapabillities`. Great it works.

**Problem?**

After form submission that div is no longer visible because their is no change to the drop down ...

So what would I have to change to make it appear after change and stay visible **AFTER** form submision

Comment: The form submit reloads the page. Changes made to the dom don't carry between page loads. Use a cookie or localStorage to keep track of when the item should be shown or hidden, or change your form submit to use ajax.

Comment: Ditto on @Jason, if you have the option of using AJAX instead of a post, I'd also suggest using that

Comment: Rather than using a cookie bake it into your back end page builder (what ever tech you are using).  Only add the hidden if there is no value.  I.E. if the  entry does not exists hidden else not hidden.  Or use what @Gobo said and use ajaz.

Comment: Alternately, if there are any other rules that you could use to determine if the section should show, you could key the display off of that on page load.  For example, could you make the assumption that, as long as the default selection was not selected, the div should show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using show(), you might want to add a class:

```
$('.carouselUser').change(function(){
    $('.sectionCarouselCapabillities').addClass('is-active');
});
```

And in your CSS:

```
.sectionCarouselCapabillities.is-active { display: block; }
```

On the server side you can check if the form is posted. If so, add the is-active class on the div already.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you'll need to set a cookie when the dropdown changes, and then read the cookie after the form submission.